# Pi 3 WiFi with airmon-ng

Tags: wifi, pi-3, kali

Yesterday I wanted to use airmon-ng on my Pi 3 with Kali. I tried 
`airmon-ng start wlan0`

But I got `??????` under the driver and the message `Operation not supported (-95)` Is it a driver issue? I used the onboard wifi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a limitation in the buildin WiFi chip's firmware. [rpi3.nexmon.org](http://rpi3.nexmon.org) has already started to provide a solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

It's currently not supported, but there are people discussing implementing it.  You'll have to use an external USB supported device.